# Are there any channels or streams for real-time research mathematics?

Tags: soft-question

Users around the world use streaming services such as YouTube or Twitch to share their activities in real-time. Sometimes these activities are exciting such as professional gaming, but sometimes quite mundane too such as [eating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mukbang).

Are there any streaming channels that share real-time development of research mathematics?

Comment: sounds like a lot of staring at the wall while sipping coffee

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Punctuated by the occasional "But what if ... oh yeah! That doesn't work, but it's my best idea yet today. Not worth writing down, though."

Comment: Eating streams aren't that exciting either, but they are popular.

Comment: Don't know about streaming, but (Fields medal winner) [Terence Tao has a blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/), where he regularly updates readers on his current thinking.